# How to make swank working with stumpw?

Tags: emacs, lisp, common-lisp, swank

I've added this code snippet to my stumpwmrc file:

```
(defun load-swank ()
  "Load a swank server"
  (ql:quickload 'swank)
  (require 'swank)
  (setq swank:*use-dedicated-output-stream* nil)
  (setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
  (swank:create-server :port 4006))
(load-swank)
```

I am expecting to open a socket server, accepting the "swank" protocol. Thus I could connect to it with emacs (thanks to Slime).

But when I login and and stumpwm is reading its configuration file, here is the error message I get:

```
15:00:34 Outputting a message:
         ^B^1*Error loading ^b/home/ybaumes/.stumpwmrc^B: ^nThe name "SWANK" does not designate any package.
```

How can I fix that? I invoke 'require, or even 'quickload functions. What's the issue here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A typical error is this:

You load the file and the reader sees the code:

SWANK is not loaded

```
(defun load-swank ()
  "Load a swank server"
```

SWANK is not loaded

```
  (ql:quickload 'swank)
```

SWANK is not loaded - remember, we are still reading the form.

```
  (require 'swank)
```

SWANK is not loaded - remember, we are still reading the form.

Now use us a symbol in package which is not existing... the reader complains:

```
  (setq swank:*use-dedicated-output-stream* nil)  ; the package SWANK does not exist yet.

  (setq slime-net-coding-system 'utf-8-unix)
  (swank:create-server :port 4006))
```

Now you want to load SWANK:

```
(load-swank)
```

You can't use a symbol from a package which does not exist.

For example what works is this inside the function:

```
(setf (symbol-value (read-from-string "swank:*use-dedicated-output-stream*")) nil)
```

and so on.

You need to find the symbol at runtime of that function. Use `(find-symbol "FOO" "SWANK")` (remember Common Lisp is upcase internally) or `(read-from-string "SWANK::FOO")`.